# Picking integer compositions with certain descent patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, combinatorics, number-theory

I am trying to find a nice way to pick out all the integer compositions (ordered partitions) of an integer $n$ that satisfy a given pattern of descents between some adjacent elements.  Writing a composition as $(c_1, \ldots, c_t)$, a simple example is requiring $c_{2k-1} > c_{2k}$ for each positive integer $k$ with no restriction on the relation between $c_{2k}$ and $c_{2k+1}$.  (Fun fact: Among the compositions of $n$, the number with this pattern is the $n$th Fibonacci number.)

I can get these from Mathematica for each possible length, for instance

```
Comps[n_] := Flatten[Map[Permutations, IntegerPartitions[n]], 1]

Cases[Comps[7], {a_, b_, _} /; a > b]
{{5, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 2}}

Cases[Comps[7], {a_, b_, c_, d_} /; a > b && c > d]
{{3, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 1}}
```

give the 3 part and 4 part intended compositions of 7, but I would like a way to find them all in one command.  (The others in the list are $\{7\}$, $\{6,1\}$, $\{5,2\}$, $\{4,3\}$, and $\{2,1,2,1,1\}$.)  Note that using `{x_, y_, __} /; x > y]` or `{x_, y_, ___} /; x > y]` includes compositions that do not follow the intended pattern beyond the first two parts.

While I can hopefully extrapolate from nice code for the $c_{2k-1} > c_{2k}$ pattern, I really want a general technique that can handle, say, $c_{3k-2} > c_{3k-1} < c_{3k}$ (with no restriction between parts $c_{3k}$ and $c_{3k+1}$).

Comment: As an example the list contains:  `... {6, 1}, {1, 6}...`. Why not select both? i.e., if there is no relation between the current and previous sequences?

Comment: @Syed The restriction is that $c_1 > c_2$, $c_3 > c_4$, etc., so $\{1,6\}$ does not meet the criterion.  Compositions are ordered summands, so $\{1,6\}$ and $\{6,1\}$ are different compositions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a recursive function to match patterns as follows:

```
test[] := True
test[a_] := True
test[a_, b_, c___] := a > b && test[c]
Cases[Comps[7], {y___} /; test[y]]
(* {{7}, {6, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 1, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 4},
{3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 1}} *)
```

Explanation:

- Empty sequence is matching
- Sequence of one element is matching
- Sequence of two or more elements: first two elements from the head
  are checked, then the tail is checked.

> I really want a general technique that can handle, say,
> $_{3−2}>_{3−1}<_{3}$ (with no restriction between parts $_{3}$ and
> $_{3+1}$).

In this case the matching function can be organized as `t[a_, b_, c_, rest___]`

Comment: Great!  Recursion to the rescue.